# Why are sarcomas rare compared to carcinomas?

Tags: human-biology, cancer, pathogenesis

> A sarcoma (from the Greek σάρξ sarx meaning "flesh") is a cancer that
>   arises from transformed cells of mesenchymal origin. Thus, malignant
>   tumors made of cancellous bone, cartilage, fat, muscle, vascular, or
>   hematopoietic tissues are, by definition, considered sarcomas. This is
>   in contrast to a malignant tumor originating from epithelial cells,
>   which are termed carcinoma. Human sarcomas are quite rare. Common
>   malignancies, such as breast, colon, and lung cancer, are almost
>   always carcinoma.

- ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcoma

I was wondering why most of the tumors come from epithelial cells?

Comment: https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT00029991 I have found something interesting. `"These cells, known as endothelial cells, are susceptible to damage by blood cholesterol, smoking or high blood pressure and, when damaged, will allow cholesterol to deposit in arteries. Antioxidants can prevent the endothelial cell damage"` - So antioxidants might prevent cancer by protecting endothelial cells from being damaged by carcinogens. If so, then atherosclerosis and high LDL cholesterol should be a risk factor of cancer. I don't remember reading of such a connection...

Comment: According to many articles and wikipedia as well obesity is linked to cancer. http://cancerpreventionresearch.aacrjournals.org/content/3/11/1451.short http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11912-010-0139-7 http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S014067360860269X According to this article fat on its own is not the cause of the cancer but changed metabolic state might be. http://cancerres.aacrjournals.org/content/67/6/2391.short

Comment: So the previous articles indirectly support that endothelial damage causes cancer.
Another interesting topic is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-area-to-volume_ratio The endothelial tissue has a high surface/volume ratio, so it might come in contact with potentially damaging compounds more often than other tissue, since these compounds tend to travel through blood. However I don't feel this a complete explanation. I think endothelial tissue is more prone to cancer somehow genetically. Probably cancers caused by ionizing radiation support this somehow, because they are not blood related.

Comment: Note that epithelial and endothelial cells are two different lineages. Carcinomas derive from *epithelium*. Tumors originating from endothelium are considered sarcomas, and they are rare. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angiosarcoma